# Polymer - notify that a object.property changed in a array for DOM

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

In Polymer 1.*, I have a dom repeat. The obj.property is not updating in the DOM when I mutate array `itemsCollection`.

I tried 'this.notifyPath(`itemCollection.${i}.value`)' after 'this.set(`itemCollection.${i}.value`, existing.value);' but it did not update in the DOM.

Am I supposed to use this.notifySplices instead? And if so, how would I use it after `this.set(`itemCollection.${i}.value`, existing.value);`?

```
  _populateAlerts: function(existingValues) {
    this.itemCollection.forEach((question, i)=> {
      const existing =
        existingValues.find(value => value.name === question.name);

      this.set(`itemCollection.${i}.picklist_value_id`,
        existing.picklist_value_id);
      this.set(`itemCollection.${i}.value`, existing.value);
    });
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

`this.notifyPath` is never needed if you use `this.set`, and should probably only be used if another framework sets the variable.

---

It's weird code, with cubic looping, and setting subproperties in `itemCollection`, while looping through said array, through Polymer methods.

Anyway, I wonder if there is an Array reference problem. Where `existingValues` = `itemCollection`, so every time `existingValues` changes, `itemCollection` is changed as well but in a way that doesn't update the DOM. This means that `itemCollection` tries to set itself to an already existing value when being set through `this.set`, hence not updating the DOM through *dirty checking*.

A simple solution could be to just set `itemCollection` with a copy of itself.

```
_populateAlerts: function(existingValues) {
  this.itemCollection.forEach((question, i)=> {
    const existing =
      existingValues.find(value => value.name === question.name);

    this.set(`itemCollection.${i}.picklist_value_id`,
      existing.picklist_value_id);
    this.set(`itemCollection.${i}.value`, existing.value);
  });

  this.set('itemCollection', JSON.parse( JSON.stringify(this.itemCollection) );

  // Alternatively
  // const tempArr = JSON.parse( JSON.stringify(this.itemCollection) );
  // this.set('itemCollection, []); // override dirty checking, as stated in the documentation
  // this.set('itemCollection', tempArr);
},
```

Another solution could be to create a new array of `existingValues`, breaking the "reference chain" so `existingValues` != `itemCollection`. That is, if the issue is a reference problem.

```
_populateAlerts: function(existingValues) {
  const copiedExistingValues = JSON.parse( JSON.stringify(existingValues) );

  this.itemCollection.forEach((question, i)=> {
    const existing =
      copiedExistingValues.find(value => value.name === question.name);

    this.set(`itemCollection.${i}.picklist_value_id`,
      existing.picklist_value_id);
    this.set(`itemCollection.${i}.value`, existing.value);
  });
},
```

However, if you're only interested in the first occurance, I would create an object of existingArrays to avoid cubic looping while also breaking the reference chain.

```
_populateAlerts: function(existingValues) {
  const existingValuesObj = this._createObjectFrom(existingValues, 'name');

  this.itemCollection.forEach((question, i)=> {
    this.set(`itemCollection.${i}.picklist_value_id`,
      existingValuesObj[question.name].picklist_value_id);
    this.set(`itemCollection.${i}.value`, existingValuesObj[question.name].value);
  });
},

_createObjectFrom: function (arr, property, overwritePreviousObj) {
  var obj = {};
  var propertyName = '';

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
     propertyName = arr[i][property];

     if (overwritePreviousObj) {
       obj[propertyName] = arr[i];
     } else if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(propertyName) {
       obj[propertyName] = arr[i];
     }
  }

  return obj;
},
```